# Are there any efficient ways to populate a balanced tree structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I have a balanced binary tree structure:

Node `0` at depth `0` is the root.
The root's left child is `1` and right child is `2`, and so on.

Please see image:[image]

The total depth of the tree is given as `N`. This `N` is the only parameter of the problem. Nodes at level `N` are designated as leaf nodes.

I am storing this tree using the following node structure.

```
struct node_s{
    int n, depth, parent;//n is node number
    int nodescendents;//number of descendents of the current node
    std::vector<int> descendents;//Descendents in ascending order
    int lchild, rchild;//Immediate left child and right child
    std::vector<int> lchildleaves;//leaf nodes that descend from the immediate 
                                                      //left child
    std::vector<int> rchildleaves;//leaf nodes that descend from the immediate 
                                                      //right child
};
```

I intend to store the tree itself as:

```
std::vector<node_s> tree;
```

Is there a way to numerically efficiently populate the `tree` vector using simple algebra roughly as:

```
//Creating the nth node, beginning from 0th node, then 1st node and so on
nodes_s node;
//populate all data structures of the nth node
//precisely, here, there are loops, algebraic calculations, etc., that can help 
//populate all of the node_s data members.
tree.push_back(node);
```

The only way I can think of as of now is to construct a graph explicitly and run some sort of Dijkstra algorithm to figure out these data structure values for each node.

Comment: Your node stucture is not usual and in particular will lead to a very large amount of memory... Are you forced to use this particular structure ?

Comment: I agree that there will be repetition. Space is unlikely to be a constraint for the time being.

Comment: Repetition implies more operations. Moreover, when adding a new node, you are obliged to modify some previous nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a node `k`, the key point is to identify its position in the graph, in order to identify its parent, if it is a left or right child.

For node k, its rank r[k] is equal to floor(log2(k+1)) and its position in the rank is equal to p[k] = k - 2^r[k] + 1

Then k is located by the pair (r[k], p[k])

Conversely, k = 2^r[k] + p[k] - 1

Its parent is then located by (r[k]-1, floor(p[k]/2)) -> node index = 2^r + p - 1

k is a left child if k%2 == 1

I guess the rest is rather easy

Comment: that is, rank(k) = ceiling(log base 2 of (k+1)) ? Then possibly multiple nodes will get mapped to the same rank. Is rank same as depth?

Comment: @Tryer You are right for what I called rank, it corresponds to the depth in the tree. I have used this terminology for ages, difficult to change. Concerning calculation, I assumed implicit conversion to integer `rank`. The nodes at the same rank (depth) are distinguished by position pk in the rank. It is a way to simply find parent position, but there may be other

Comment: I think you can edit your answer as r[k] = floor(log base 2 [k+1]). Then, its position is p[k] = k - 2^r[k] + 1. The parent then is (r[k]-1, floor(p[k]/2))

Comment: @Tryer Thank you for the correction on 'k' calculation. I was assuming that floor(.) was implicit but no problem to add it. Edit done

Comment: @Tryer `log2(.)` is C++ !