# Finding common parent in perfect binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

This question:

[Are there any efficient ways to populate a balanced tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349791/are-there-any-efficient-ways-to-populate-a-balanced-tree-structure)

provides an analytical way of labelling a perfect binary tree of any depth.

In such a tree, is there any way of efficiently figuring out the first common parent of an arbitrary subset of leaf nodes?

For instance, given the following binary tree:

[image]

I am looking for a way where if:

Input is: `3,5` Output is: `0`

Input is: `3,5,6` Output is: `0`

Input is: `3,4` Output is: `1`

The only way I can think of is to traverse up to the root (0) from each of the given leaf nodes, and then picking the first common one.

Is there any closed-form analytical way in which the first common parent can be found?

Comment: It seems that with "balanced binary tree", you actually mean "perfect binary tree". See [difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees). Can you clarify?

Comment: @trincot yes, it is a perfect binary tree, every nonleaf node has exactly two children, every child has exactly one parent, depth is same for all leaf nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `H` be height of your tree, and let `k` be the count of numbers in your input.

If you start numeration of nodes from 1 and write nodes' binary numbers, it will become clear that number of every node is prefix of numbers of all its children. So, to find the lowest common ancestor, you should find the greatest common prefix (GCP) of binary numbers.

[image]

Let `min` and `max` be minimal and maximal numbers in your subset. If numbers in your input are already sorted, your can find `min` and `max` in `O(1)`. If they are not sorted, you can find `min` and `max` in `O(k * H)`.

The GCP of all binary numbers is the GCP of `min` and `max` - you can find it trivially in `O(H)`.

This algorithm works in `O(H)` if numbers are sorted and in `O(k * H)` otherwise (although your algorithm works in `O(k * H)` too if you implement it right).

Comment: Nice +1. So, it's longest common prefix in binary representation among all  `K` values. Also, if I get your algorithm correctly, if data is not sorted, I think we can put all values in map and get the actual parent from it. We wouldn't need sorting this way. If duplicates values exist, we put the node reference itself in the map which will always be unique.

Comment: GCP of [10, 11, 101] is not the GCP of [10,101].  You need to find min and max lexically, not numerically

Comment: A good quick way:  Find the smallest number. That's min.  Shift all the other numbers right until they're <= min, and keep the highest result.  That's max.  Repeatedly shift the higher of min and max until they're the same.  That's the common parent.

Comment: @Tryer said that subset contains only leaf nodes, so the number of binary digits for all numbers is the same, so numerically minimal == lexically minimal in this case. But for general case, of course, it should be lexically minimal.